# Failing to upgrade to linux-image-3.0.0-26-generic

Tags: upgrade, kernel, dependencies

When I try to upgrade `linux-image-3.0.0-26-generic` I get following problems:

```
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal bzip2 read error: 'DATA_ERROR'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.0.0-26-generic_3.0.0-26.42_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 short read on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./lib/modules/3.0.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/fnic/fnic.ko'
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.0.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.0.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-26-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.0.0-26-generic_3.0.0-26.42_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.0.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.0.0-26-generic is not installed.
```

I don't know why this happens to me; earlier upgrades always worked without problems.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the .deb package is corrupt, see [this article](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/06/27/deciphering-one-of-dpkgs-weirdest-errors-short-read-on-buffer-copy/) for further explanation.

Solution:

```
apt-get clean # clears out the local repository of retrieved package files
```

Comment: Thank you! You were exactly right. Now it works like a breeze :)

Answer (score -2):

try this 
`sudo apt-get install linux-image-`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

it will show you all the possible kernel image which will support your system